# Extreme Climate Change(Sulfur Hexafluoride)

Tags: science-based, gas

So say I have a planet which is 100 earth masses compressed to only 5 earth radii in volume and it has 20 earth masses of osmium in it making the osmium portion only one earth radii. The atmosphere is 99.9% sulfur hexafluoride and 0.1 percent water vapor. Say it is orbiting a sun-like star at 1.5 AU. How hot would the planet get and would it actually gain enough energy to get heavier?And also to prevent convection from causing significant amounts of energy from being sent back, the planet has some chemicals where when a certain part of the upper atmosphere gets too hot, glucose molecules form from some of the carbon dioxide and water.

How long could this planet hold the heat assuming it was kept at that 1.5 AU for 4 billion years and then thrown into interstellar space. Assume that the planet didn't have internal heat because aliens took all of it out but forgot to take out the heat from the star because they thought they could store the energy but forgot to bring the battery and will take them 10 billion years for them to create a battery to store the energy so the star's energy can still shine on the planet.

Comment: *"Would it actually gain enough energy to get heavier?"* What does this even mean? (Oh, and you may want to check you math. A planet with a radius five times as large as Earth's has a volume **125** times as large as Earth's. If the mass of the planet is only 100 times as large as Earth's then the density of the planet must be only 80% of the density of Earth. There is no need for the osmium...) P.S. A sphere of osmium with a radius equal to Earth's has a mass only 4 times as large as Earth. Don't know where you got the 20 Earth masses from.

Comment: Where would you get all the fluorine and osmium from? If you want a science-based answer, you could start with elements that are commonly produced by stellar processes, such as hydrogen, helium, oxygen, carbon, neon, nitrogen, magnesium, silicon, iron... Fluorine is pretty rare. Even chlorine, which we have in our oceans, is pretty rare but it makes soluble salts, so it collects in water. 

What do you think the gravity is on your planet? It won't be 100G even if it is 100x more massive. It will be less because the planet is bigger.

Comment: @AlexP The osmium is there for there to be sufficient gravity to hold on to the 80 earth masses of sf6, for the extreme greenhouse gas effect. Also lets say that the aliens accidently dropped a whole bunch of sulfur hexafluoride onto the planet during a intergalactic war between two sets of aliens.